# Where to find datasheet for male/plug HDMI connectors?

Tags: connector, hdmi

Okay I know this might sound like a silly question....

But I CANNOT find these on Digi-Key or Mouser. Am I just stupid and searching for the wrong thing? Almost all websites sell the receptacle...I need the plug! I just need a male HDMI connector for a PCB I'm making. The reason I want it from there is so I can get a good datasheet, as I need to make a footprint for them. I don't want to buy some AliExpress and wait 6 months

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: "I'm looking for a supplier." That's off topic.  Transistor was trying to help you avoid your question being closed.

Comment: @JRE oh well I feel silly now. Thanks. I don't think this should be rocket science so I'm just very confused hoping someone knows.

Comment: Why would you make a PCB with male plug, what is it you are making, why does it need a male plug?

Comment: @Justme custom adapter for a client. It HAS to be this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would approach the problem of finding a PCB mountable plug, for a system like HDMI where the PCB typically has the receptacle and the cable has the plug...

One connector manufacturer that I use frequently is samtec.com, because they have clear, concise drawings in their catalog pages (in fact their catalog is mostly drawings and part number tables), and they also give free samples.

A quick search on samtec's website shows they offer a lot of part numbers like HDMR-xxx and a few cable assemblies with part numbers HDMP-xxxx... so HDMR means HDMI Receptacle and HDMP must mean HDMI Plug.

One approach would be to contact Applications Engineering and ask if they can sell you the HDMI Plug that is normally part of their HDMI cable assemblies.

I also found that they have a part number HDMP-19-01-S-EM which is described as "Conn SCSI PL 19 POS 0.5mm Solder ST Edge Mount 19 Terminal 1 Port" -- that may be what you want, or at least something close. Wasn't able to find drawing online.

At any rate, I think your next step is to actually contact Application Engineering at samtec (or another connector manufacturer), see if they can provide drawing/CAD footprint, and request a few samples. Once you have the parts in hand, you can confirm that they really are the right type of connector (plug/receptacle) and mechanically fit for purpose.

*(I'm not affiliated with samtec, but they have given me lots of free samples over the years, and we've bought a lot of parts from them.)*

Comment: Thank you! Im so used to being able to pick up small quantities from Mouser I was very surprised I wasn't able to find them. I guess it's time to up my game to cut out the middle man :)

Answer (score 1):

Find a real manufacturer and then either download the datasheet from their website or contact them with your request and hope they reply. For example, this barely readable one from Dongguan Jin Hong Wei:

[image]

If you have a serious business need, pay the extra for a courier for samples as well, it’s nothing in comparison to the cost of engineering time.

Comment: But that's a picture of a standard SMT socket, right? OP is searching for SMT mounted plug, and plugs are normally only on cables. Some test equipment do exist with SMT plugs.

Comment: @Justme yes, the drawing does not match the photo of the HAF019BS part (HDMI male vertical mount) it was associated with, but the manufacturer (or some other maker) may be able to supply the correct readable datasheet. .